# Group $G$ with $N\unlhd G$, $|N|=5$ and $G/N\cong S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Group $G$ with $N\unlhd G$, $|N|=5$ and $G/N\cong S_3$.

Question is : Let $G$ be a group with a normal subgroup $N\unlhd G$ of order $5$, such that $G/N\cong S_3$. Show that, $|G|=30$, $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $15$, and $G$ has $3$ subgroups of order $10$ that are not Normal.

Intuitively, this is very clear But I am Not so sure how to write this in detail.

As $|N|=5$ and $|S_3|=6$ and $G/N\cong S_3$ we have $|G/N|=|S_3|$ which implies $|G|=|N|.|S_3|=5.6=30$ (DONE).

$S_3$ has Normal Subgroup of order $3$ which is $H=\{(1)(2)(3), (123),(132)\}$, and so, I somehow see that $H\times N$ is normal group with $|H\times N|=|H||N|=3.5=15$ (PARTIALLY DONE)

$S_3$ has $3$ Non-Normal (:)) subgroups  of order $2$. $H_1=\{(1)(2)(3), (12)\}$, $H_2=\{(1)(2)(3), (13)\}$, $H_3=\{(1)(2)(3), (23)\}$, We consider $N\times H_1$, $N\times H_2$, $N\times H_3$ are required subgroups of order $10$ which are Non-normal. (PARTIALLY DONE)

I am not very sure about the way i have Justified this.

Please let me know if there is any possible better way for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In fact when $G/N\cong S_3$ so $G$ is an extention of $N$ by $S_3$ so $G\cong N\rtimes S_3$ and this gives you $|G|=30$. Also, according to well-known fact:

> If $|G|=2n$ in which $n$ is odd then $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

our group $G$ has a subgroup of order $15$ which is also a normal one. If you are familiar to the presentaion of groups, with a good knowledge of semidirect product, then you may find the following presentaion for $G$:
 $$G=\langle a,b\mid a^2=1=abab^4\rangle$$

The following codes might help you when using GAP:

```
   > f:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
   > a:=f.1;;  b:=f.2;; 
   > s:=f/[a^2,a*b*a*b^4];;
     Order(s);
     StructureDescription(s);
     IsAbelian(s);

     30
     "C5 x S3"
     false
```

Comment: Nice work, @Babak! +1

Answer (score 1):

This is basically just an application of the lattice isomorphism theorem.

For example, you noted that $S_3$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $3$ which is normal. Then, by the lattice isomorphism theorem there exists a subgroup $N\subseteq K\subseteq G$ such that under the projection $G\to G/N$ one has that $K$ mapsto $H$. You know that this has order $15$ since $K/N$ has order $3$. You also know it's normal since the isomorphism $G\to S_3\to S_3/H$ has kernel $K$.

Try and apply this logic to solve your other question.

Comment: +1 Alex, and I like your explanation! Also, it's worth adding that since $N$ has order $5$ (a prime number), every subgroup of $G$ either intersects $N$ trivially or contains $N$. It's impossible to have a subgroup of $G$ of order exceeding $6$ intersecting $N$ trivially so that means that all subgroups of $G$ of orders $10$ and $15$ must contain $N$. The rest then follows from the lattice isomorphism theorem (personally, I call it the correspondence theorem!) as you nicely explain. (A priori, this extra argument might be necessary if we wish to know *precisely* how many subgroups there are.)

Comment: @AmiteshDatta Of course! It's also easily deducable from the fact that the sequence $1\to N\to G\to S_3\to 1$ must split. But, that seems a bit overkill in this case.

Comment: @AlexYoucis : I was actually expecting a "EDIT" for my Explanation rather than Another Answer. But then, It is more clear now. Thank You!